# JQuery on keydown event to focus to a button seems to automatically press the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus, onkeydown

I have two text inputs and a button.

For both text inputs, I set a `keydown` event with JQuery to switch focus to the next element on pressing Enter.

So:

- Pressing Enter while in the first input should focus to the second input.
- Pressing Enter while in the second input should focus to the button.

```js
var counter = 0;
function Foo() 
{
 $('#output').html(++counter); 
}

function FocusToLastName(evt)
{
 var keyCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which; 
  if (keyCode==13) $('#lastname').focus();
}

function FocusToButton(evt)
{
 var keyCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which; 
  if (keyCode==13) $('#btn').focus();
}

$('#firstname').on('keydown',FocusToLastName);
$('#lastname').on('keydown',FocusToButton);
$('#firstname').focus();
```

```css
#output { color:#0f0; background:#80f; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='firstname' type='text'>
<input id='lastname' type='text'>
<button id='btn' onclick='Foo()'>OK</button>
<h1 id='output'></h1>
```

To see what happens:

1. Click on first input field to set focus there.
2. Press Enter. Focus will move to second input field (correct).
3. Press Enter again. Focus will move to the button (correct) **however the button's onclick event is also triggered (NOT correct)**

Note that this *only* happens when I use the Enter key. If I change the `keyCode` condition to 40 instead of 13 (for cursor key down <kbd>↓</kbd> instead of Enter) in both event handlers, it works as expected.

Additionally, another small problem: I automatically focus to the first input element which doesn't seem to work. But that may be related to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the default event. Use the `event.preventDefault()` method to do so in your focus to button function like so :

```
function FocusToButton(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which; 
    if (keyCode==13) $('#btn').focus();
}
```

It would be a good idea to add it to other functions as well. Read more on preventDefault() [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)